# Create a material .NET Connector SAP

Tags: c#, .net, sap-dotnet-connector

Please tell me somebody out there has done this. I am trying to interface with SAP via .NET Connector 3.0. I can read data fine with the remote function calls, but I cannot figure out how to write anything, creating or editing a material for example. Through some research I have determined that `BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA` is the RFC I need to be using, but cannot for the life of me figure out how. Here's what I'm trying:

```
function = destination.Repository.CreateFunction("BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA");
IRfcStructure structure = function.GetStructure("HEADDATA");
structure.SetValue("material", "000000000000000888");
structure.SetValue("ind_sector", "U");
structure.SetValue("matl_type", "ERSA");
structure.SetValue("basic_view", "X");

structure = function.GetStructure("CLIENTDATA");
structure.SetValue("matl_group", "01");
structure.SetValue("base_uom", "EA");

structure = function.GetStructure("CLIENTDATAX");
structure.SetValue("matl_group", "X");
structure.SetValue("base_uom", "X");
function.Invoke(destination);
```

I cobbled this together based on a various VB and ABAP examples. The problem is it does nothing. When `function.Invoke()` is called, it doesn't create a material, it doesn't throw an exception, it just does nothing. Clearly I am not doing something right be I haven't the slightest idea what. Somebody please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no access to a SAP system at the moment, but as far as I know, you have to call the bapi within a transactional scope, e.g. call BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT after creating the material. But maybe the .net connector has another approach for that...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep try calling BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT if BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA returns successfully.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Apparently I was misunderstanding the issue here. I was expecting the function to throw an exception if it failed, but I realized that is not the case. I checked the return from the function and it is in fact failing and telling me why. It says that "no description has been transferred" however I do not know where it wants me to put it. The MATERIALDESCRIPTION table? If so, it will not let me modify this table. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have to access the table MATERIALDESCRIPTION, yes, by using

IRfcTable matdescr = function.GetTable(“MATERIALDESCRIPTION”);

and then add a new row, enter the data (don't forget to include the language!) and call the function as you would normally do.

Comment: Thank you again sir I was trying to do a table.SetValue() without ever adding a row! Last question, is there anywhere that tells you what are the required fields for material creation? Stepping through the code and reading the return error message to find out the next thing I am missing is kind of a pain in the ass.

Comment: You could check the transaction BAPI in a SAP system. You will find the documentation of most of the bapis there. Another good source is the SAP Developer Network. They have a lot of forums where you can get help: http://sdn.sap.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value from the function, based on the output type. Below example for the output type. (table)

```
    function.Invoke(rfcDest);

    IRfcTable TableResult = function.GetTable("TAG_NAME_OR_METADATA_NAME");
```