# How to call BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA with custom fields from NCo?

Tags: bapi, sap-dotnet-connector, sap-erp

In our current project we are using SAPNCO3 with RFC calls. The requirement is to create material with the function "BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA" and some custom fields (via EXTENSIONIN). The problem now is how to extend the needed structures "BAPI_TE_MARA/X" so that they can carry the custom fields? I cannot found any function for this.

Please have a look at the Code snippet at the bottom.

Thank you!

Tobias

```
            var BAPI_TE_MARA = repo.GetStructureMetadata("BAPI_TE_MARA");
            IRfcStructure structure = BAPI_TE_MARA.CreateStructure();
           
            structure.SetValue("MATERIAL", material.Number);
            //structure.SetValue("ZMM_JOB_REFERENCE", "f");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a material .NET Connector SAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332419/create-a-material-net-connector-sap)

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: if the question is how to extend then no way, you cannot extend the interface from NCO, it should be done on backend. And I don't see `BAPI_TE_MARA` is used in `BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA`, only `BAPI_MARA`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the question. Please have a look at this excerpt from https://answers.sap.com/questions/8538871/%27bapimaterialsavedata%27-using-extension.html:  

 "BAPI_TE_MARA and BAPI_TE_MARAX are the standard structures to be used with any BAPI that updates MARA.

First you need to open BAPI_TE_MARA and append your custom structure ZZCNAME.

Once you do that, BAPI_TE_MARA will have three fields"

This sounds to me like BAPI_TE_MARA is mandatory for using custom fields.

Answer (score 2):

`BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA` has two table parameters `EXTENSIONIN` and `EXTENSIONINX` to which you pass lines with the values of your custom fields.

These table parameters have to indicate what extension structures you want to use and their values.

As these custom fields may extend different tables of the material, you have to indicate different extension structures depending on which table these fields belong to:

- For the table `MARA`, the extension structures are `BAPI_TE_MARA` and `BAPI_TE_MARAX`.
- For the table `MARC`, the extension structures are `BAPI_TE_MARC` and `BAPI_TE_MARCX`.

These extension structures should preferably have character-like fields to simplify the programming (and to support IDocs, as rule-of-thumb).

For instance, if you have the custom fields `ZZCNAME` (7 characters) and `ZZCTEXT` (50 characters) in the table `MARA`, they will also be defined in `BAPI_TE_MARA` and have the same names and types. In `BAPI_TE_MARAX`, you also have two fields with the same names, but always of length 1 character and their values must be 'X' to indicate that a value is passed in `BAPI_TE_MARA` (useful in case a blank value is passed that must not be ignored). The X extension structures are essential especially in "change" BAPIs.

If you want to pass values to the BAPI, you must first initialize these structures:

- `BAPI_TE_MARA`:

  ```
  MATERIAL      ZZCNAME  ZZCTEXT
  ------------  -------  -------
  000000012661  NAME     TEXT
  ```
- `BAPI_TE_MARAX`:

  ```
  MATERIAL      ZZCNAME  ZZCTEXT
  ------------  -------  -------
  000000012661  X        X
  ```

Then, you must initialize the two parameters of the BAPI:

- `EXTENSIONIN` (notice that there are 3 spaces in `NAME   TEXT` because the technical length of `ZZCNAME` is 7 characters and its value "NAME" occupies only 4 characters):

  ```
  STRUCTURE     VALUEPART1 (240 Char)    VALUEPART2 (240)  VALUEPART3 (240)  VALUEPART4 (240)
  ------------  -----------------------  ----------------  ----------------  ----------------
  BAPI_TE_MARA  000000012661NAME   TEXT
  ```
- `EXTENSIONINX`:

  ```
  STRUCTURE      VALUEPART1 (240 Char)  VALUEPART2 (240)  VALUEPART3 (240)  VALUEPART4 (240)
  -------------  ---------------------  ----------------  ----------------  ----------------
  BAPI_TE_MARAX  000000012661XX
  ```

Consequently, your program must:

- concatenate all `BAPI_TE_MARA` fields together and copy the resulting string into fields `VALUEPART1` to `VALUEPART4` of `EXTENSIONIN` as if it was a 960 characters field
- concatenate all `BAPI_TE_MARAX` fields together and copy the resulting string into fields `VALUEPART1` to `VALUEPART4` of `EXTENSIONINX`

I guess you may use `ToString()` to get one concatenated string of characters of all fields of a structure, and to set the value of `VALUEPART1`, `VALUEPART2`, etc., you'll probably need to initialize them individually from the string of characters with `Substring`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailled answer!

I think I understood the samples but I still need to know how to transfer this to our case which differs a little bit.
At this If I load BAPI_TE_MARA there aren't any custom fields but the material. In my code snippet above I try to SetValue for custom field ZMM_JOB_REFERENCE which fails.  
From our SAP team I found out today that a custom structure called ZMM_S_MATMAS_ADDITION holds the custom fields.  
So I think I have to load this structure and reference it at EXTENSIONIN instead of BAPI_TE_MARA? Or do I need BAPI_TE_MARA in any case?

Comment: From what you say, it seems that the SAP team added custom fields in a way that cannot be updated by the BAPI. Consequently, you cannot use the BAPI. Please ask your local SAP team how to update these custom fields via a RFC call.

Comment: Hm that's bad. So BAPI_TE_MARA is really needed in any case? User "Suncatcher" answered above that this structure can be ignored.
But I will ask the SAP team.

Comment: No, I discard my comment, it cannot be ignored. See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

My comment was half by half correct and incorrect, I wasn't aware of the extension technique in this BAPI, so I wasn't aware of this structure is really used in this BAPI.

You asked

> The problem now is how to extend the needed structures "BAPI_TE_MARA/X" so that they can carry the custom fields?`

and what I said is indeed stays valid: **you cant extend the interface from NCo, only on backend**.

You writes:

> At this If I load BAPI_TE_MARA there aren't any custom fields but the material

and this get me to the idea that your ABAP developers made only half of the work. The things to be done on the SAP backend:

1. Extend `MARA` table with custom Z fields (in SAP it is called *Append structure*)
2. Extend interface structure `BAPI_TE_MARA` with the fields which should exactly correspond to the `MARA` fields

This is how it must look like on backend

[image]

If you don't see any custom fields in `BAPI_TE_MARA` except `MATERIAL` probably step 2 is missing on SAP side. As what I got from your comments, they created structure `ZMM_S_MATMAS_ADDITION` but appended it only to `MARA`, but not to `BAPI_TE_MARA`.

What is missing from Sandra excellent holistic answer is step 3: for all this construction to work some customizing need to be done.

3. `T130F` table must contain your custom fields. To maintain the entry for T130F go to transaction `SPRO` or directly to maintenance view `V_130F`.

SPRO way: go to `SPRO -> Logistics-General -> Material Master -> Field Selection -> Assign fields to field Selection Groups` and maintain the entry in the table

Sample ABAP code that does the thing:

```
DATA: ls_headdata      TYPE bapimathead,
      lt_extensionin   TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapiparex,
      ls_extensionin   LIKE LINE OF lt_extensionin,
      lt_extensioninx  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapiparexx,
      ls_extensioninx  LIKE LINE OF lt_extensioninx,
      lt_messages      TYPE bapiret2_t,
      ls_bapi_te_mara  TYPE bapi_te_mara,
      ls_bapi_te_marax TYPE bapi_te_marax.

ls_headdata-material = |{ ls_headdata-material ALPHA = IN }|.
ls_headdata-basic_view = 'X'.

ls_bapi_te_mara-material = ls_headdata-material.
ls_bapi_te_mara-zztest1  = '322223'.

ls_bapi_te_marax-material = ls_headdata-material.
ls_bapi_te_marax-zztest1  = 'X'.

ls_extensionin-structure  = 'BAPI_TE_MARA'.
ls_extensionin-valuepart1 = ls_bapi_te_mara
APPEND ls_extensionin TO lt_extensionin.

ls_extensioninx-structure = 'BAPI_TE_MARAX'.
ls_extensioninx-valuepart1 = ls_bapi_te_marax-zztest1.
APPEND ls_extensioninx TO lt_extensioninx.

CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA'
  EXPORTING
    headdata       = ls_headdata
  TABLES
    returnmessages = lt_messages
    extensionin    = lt_extensionin
    extensioninx   = lt_extensioninx.

CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'
  EXPORTING
    wait = 'X'.
```

Based on this you can model your .Net code for BAPI calling.

**P.S.** Pay attention to the first line with `ALPHA = IN`. The input to the material number field must be in fully qualified 18-char format with leading zeroes, e.g. `000000000000323`, otherwise the update will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Always extend structure EMARA and not MARA, BAPI_TE_MARA, ... directly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).